# What are the benefits of learning Lisp (or a dialect) if you have a good grasp of functional programming

Tags: lisp

Basically, what I'm asking is, when people say that learning Lisp will enlighten you, are they just talking about learning functional programming in general or is there some deeper benefit?

Personally, and I'm sure most people feel like this, I'm quite scared by the syntax. I feel like it gets in the way and I don't see the benefit in having all expressions look the same. Never had a problem interpreting expressions in a language...

However, Haskell was a beast as well, but after learning it I can confirm that I approach problems differently and that it was a worthwhile experience.

So, the question is. Is it worth it? What does Lisp offer that NO other languages offer? I know people are eager to promote the language they use, but if there are other languages that took the good parts of Lisp and incorporated them in a more manageable form, then I don't see a reason to learn Lisp specifically.

Answer (score 4):

### Lisp is the programmable programming language

Lisp offers something no other language does - "code is data".

This means that the code you write is a *list* which can be processed by Lisp.

This leads to a powerful macro facility, which means that you have the full power of Lisp itself at macroexpansion time.

Far more from merely adding new syntactic constructs like `with-something`, one can define a whole DSL in a few forms.

More information:

1. [Examples of what Lisp's macros can be used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561221/examples-of-what-lisps-macros-can-be-used-for)
2. [Lisp Macro](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LispMacro)
3. [Macros: Defining Your Own](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html)
4. http://weitz.de/macros.lisp

Comment: What about http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-macros.html

Comment: @LukaHorvat: CL macros are _much_ more than a mere code transformation tool.